# How to configure services within a dotnet plugin project?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, plugins, .net-6.0

## Situation

The situation I have is as follows:

- Root project (.net 6.0 - Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web)
- Plugin project (.net 6.0 - Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor)

The plugin project is loaded into the root project via assembly loading:

```cs
private void LoadModuleAssemblies(IMvcBuilder mvcBuilder)
{
    var modules = Modules.Select(module =>
    {
        if (!File.Exists(module.ModulePath))
        {
            throw new Exception($"The DLL of module {module.Name} could not be found at ({module.ModulePath})");
        }

        var loadContext = new ModuleLoadContext(module.ModulePath);
        var assembly = loadContext.LoadFromAssemblyName(new AssemblyName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(module.ModulePath)));
        mvcBuilder.AddApplicationPart(assembly);
        module.Assembly = assembly;

        return module;
    }).ToList();

    _hbsModulesAccessor.Modules = modules;
}
```

The ModuleLoadContext is used to load dependency assemblies in a different context, preventing version conflicts.

```cs
public class ModuleLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
{
    private readonly AssemblyDependencyResolver _resolver;

    public ModuleLoadContext(string pluginPath)
    {
        _resolver = new AssemblyDependencyResolver(pluginPath);
    }

    protected override Assembly? Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        var existingAssembly = Default.Assemblies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetName().Name == assemblyName.Name && x.GetName().Version == assemblyName.Version);
        if (existingAssembly != null)
        {
            return existingAssembly;
        }

        string? assemblyPath = _resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath(assemblyName);
        if (assemblyPath != null)
        {
            return LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected override IntPtr LoadUnmanagedDll(string unmanagedDllName)
    {
        string? libraryPath = _resolver.ResolveUnmanagedDllToPath(unmanagedDllName);
        if (libraryPath != null)
        {
            return LoadUnmanagedDllFromPath(libraryPath);
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

When the plugin is loaded into the assembly, I want to configure the services for the plugin:

```cs
IEnumerable<Type> moduleStartupConfigurations = AppDomainTypeFinder.FindClassesOfType<IHBSStartup>();
IOrderedEnumerable<IStartup?> instances = moduleStartupConfigurations
    .Select(s => Activator.CreateInstance(s) as IStartup)
    .OrderBy(s => s?.Order);

foreach (IStartup? instance in instances)
{
    if (instance == null) throw new Exception("Could not load plugin");
    instance.ConfigureServices(services);
}
```

The `AppDomainTypeFinder` finds the class that implements `IStartup`.
After the instance is created the ConfigureServices method defined in the plugin is called.

## Problem

And that is where the problem occurs...

When ConfigureServices is called it throws the following exception:

`Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapper(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Reflection.Assembly[])`

The Plugin class implementing IStartup is as follows:

```cs
public class Startup : IStartup
{
    public int Order { get; } = 10;

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        // Add application parts
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
    }
}
```

`AddAutoMapper` uses `IServiceCollection` to register its own services. Can this problem be caused by the fact I use a seperate AssemblyLoadContext?

I followed the following guide to create a plugin system: [Create a .NET Core application with plugins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support)

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of investigating, debugging and trying I finally got it to work.

The problem was that `Microsoft.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` version `7.0.0` was loaded by the root project.

When the plugin project tries to use AddAutoMapper, the `Microsoft.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` package from `AutoMapper` was loaded, which uses version `5.0.0`. The dependecy was then loaded into the `ModuleLoadContext`.

The `IServiceCollection` provided by the root project was from a different dll then the `ModuleLoadContext` used in `AutoMapper`.

To fix the issue I updated the `ModuleLoadContext` to force some dependencies to be loaded from the **Default AssemblyLoadContext**.

```cs
public class ModuleLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
    {
        private readonly AssemblyDependencyResolver _resolver;
        private readonly List<string> _defaultAssemblyNames = new()
        {
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions",
            "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions",
        };
        public ModuleLoadContext(string name, string pluginPath) : base(name)
        {
            _resolver = new AssemblyDependencyResolver(pluginPath);
        }
        protected override Assembly? Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
        {
            // If the assembly is one of the default assemblies, load it from the default context
            // This is done to prevent duplicate assemblies to be loaded with different versions.
            // When loading a plugin which uses AutoMapper or EntityFramework,
            // which itself uses IServiceCollection from an older version of Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
            // the plugin will throw a 'MissingMethodException', because the IServiceCollection cannot be found.
            if (_defaultAssemblyNames.Contains(assemblyName.Name!))
            {
                var defaultAssembly = GetAssemblyByName(assemblyName, false);
                if (defaultAssembly != null)
                {
                    return defaultAssembly;
                }
                return Default.LoadFromAssemblyName(assemblyName);
            }
            // If the assembly is already loaded within the default context and is the same version, return it
            var existingAssembly = GetAssemblyByName(assemblyName, true);
            if (existingAssembly != null)
            {
                return existingAssembly;
            }
            // If the assembly is not loaded yet, try to load it from the plugin path
            string? assemblyPath = _resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath(assemblyName);
            if (assemblyPath != null)
            {
                return LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected override IntPtr LoadUnmanagedDll(string unmanagedDllName)
        {
            string? libraryPath = _resolver.ResolveUnmanagedDllToPath(unmanagedDllName);
            if (libraryPath != null)
            {
                return LoadUnmanagedDllFromPath(libraryPath);
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        private static Assembly? GetAssemblyByName(AssemblyName assemblyName, bool checkVersion = true)
        {
            return Default.Assemblies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetName().Name == assemblyName.Name && (!checkVersion || x.GetName().Version == assemblyName.Version));
        }
    }
```